# Isolating elements from a specific column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I've been experimenting with the TikTok Scraper tool (https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper/) for a little while and, while I'm not a expert, I've been using R for some of the more simples analysis of the scraped data, but I've experiencing issues with the hashtags scraping.

Whenever I scrape data from, let's say, an specific hashtag, I receive data in a format that's not very suitable for my work, for instance:

```
***[{"id":"1662240138893317","name":"globolixoo","title":"","cover":""},{"id":"56170","name":"mentira","title":"","cover":""}]***
```

All that interests to me are the terms that come after ***"name":*** — that is, 'globolixoo' and 'mentira'.

Is there any way in which I can isolate these terms and separate them by comma (globolixoo,mentira)?

Reproducible code example:

```
    dput(head(globolixoo, 10)

    structure(list(id = c(6808536063938710528, 6814233256737786880, 
6825734509393103872, 6945455970969488384, 6949635086916635648, 
6970340938765978624, 6971908200639630336, 6973074032547613696, 
6973112184809212928, 6973333129226505216), secretID = c(6808536063938710528, 
6814233256737786880, 6825734509393103872, 6945455970969488384, 
6949635086916635648, 6970340938765978624, 6971908200639630336, 
6973074032547613696, 6973112184809212928, 6973333129226505216
), webVideoUrl = c("https://www.tiktok.com/@aguiarsillvabarbe/video/6808536063938710790", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@deysetavares77/video/6814233256737787141", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@davinunesrocha1988/video/6825734509393104134", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@fernandomedeiros84/video/6945455970969488646", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@marcoaaspm/video/6949635086916635909", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@diverticity/video/6970340938765978885", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@erick.castrooficial/video/6971908200639630597", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@dublagem19/video/6973074032547613958", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@dublagem19/video/6973112184809213189", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@dublagem19/video/6973333129226505478"
), text = c("#GloboLixoo", "#globolixoo", "#GLOBOLIXOO ", 
"#GloboLixoo", "#globolixoo", "#globolixoo #mentira kkkkkkk", 
"E assim foi a minha chegada aqui... valeu galera ❤️ #lulaxbolsonaro #globolixoo x #bolsonaro2022 #foryou #fory #fyyy #golpista #obrigadogalera", 
"Responder a @luizguilhermeol2 #flamengooooo #paravocefo #dublagem19 #flamengosergipe #copaamerica #flamengo #flamengolibertadores #Eriksen #globolixoo", 
"Responder a @vinicius.almeida829 #globolixoo #flamengolibertadores #flamengo #copaamerica #flamengosergipe #dublagem19 #neymar #globol", 
"#neymar #Eriksen #globolixoo #flamengolibertadores #dublagem19 #flamengosergipe #copaamerica #foryoupage #paravoce #globolixooo #flamengo #fyyy"
), createTime = c(1585235836L, 1586562318L, 1589240162L, 1617114988L, 
1618088013L, 1622908971L, 1623273877L, 1623545319L, 1623554204L, 
1623605644L), date = c("26/03/2020", "10/04/2020", "11/05/2020", 
"30/03/2021", "10/04/2021", "05/06/2021", "09/06/2021", "13/06/2021", 
"13/06/2021", "13/06/2021"), authorMeta.id = c(6807209790076404736, 
6808216797218505728, 6822488437678539776, 6573364480217792512, 
6949596571051525120, 6801837537368605696, 6817099676148990976, 
6890609472302023680, 6890609472302023680, 6890609472302023680
), authorMeta.secUid = c("MS4wLjABAAAAUCftiaqGW7kGk4tZlB2socpml7caR7G1BWDVPCMoZeYPYxujhgejBN79QwvG47Ux", 
"MS4wLjABAAAANtz2eThsfv8a4hhYR3pX1u2IBHhIX6cQfd9yefX7BjTph4ZafKiw68EYJF3fuqj9", 
"MS4wLjABAAAAasFrM5NNvAW8xmzQHoI26Boc1FDwureCXdg2kC5i7maZJRxrtehC_SGJmYRx0cvf", 
"MS4wLjABAAAAlepLE-8A44KU_01sgDHePJ0W4XP3EjRYSuOAssGWuGKj_vP2lpyX-OucAhZTmHMF", 
"MS4wLjABAAAANc_0vx6MTxJZYFTWUAgyKfG8yzgyW6ujL-pVYsKKpYom2YyhTeOWItG9bEN70fZW", 
"MS4wLjABAAAAK10peXSI-KJUKrtQQ_SeWMO4QS7NbxII7BwzudZFY4aws4UdhpjgQ-_0N4bgtQAF", 
"MS4wLjABAAAATIlZhohPSapj2p7BEUMG6JM4uQJ9S85Qeg2V_f-il28SnrBMezeIpz6SKuDZVqNN", 
"MS4wLjABAAAADWuMEBp9pN_j63r3o8eKwOqxArviqnWQvs-ENGvU03_XPiF2h2ttQubAws_xr3De", 
"MS4wLjABAAAADWuMEBp9pN_j63r3o8eKwOqxArviqnWQvs-ENGvU03_XPiF2h2ttQubAws_xr3De", 
"MS4wLjABAAAADWuMEBp9pN_j63r3o8eKwOqxArviqnWQvs-ENGvU03_XPiF2h2ttQubAws_xr3De"
), authorMeta.name = c("aguiarsillvabarbe", "deysetavares77", 
"davinunesrocha1988", "fernandomedeiros84", "marcoaaspm", "diverticity", 
"erick.castrooficial", "dublagem19", "dublagem19", "dublagem19"
), authorMeta.nickName = c("Aguiar Sillva Barbei", "Kayque Jesus", 
"Davi Nunes Rocha", "Fernando Medeiros", "user9898887549048", 
"diverticity", "Erick Rosário", "Ramon Santos", "Ramon Santos", 
"Ramon Santos"), authorMeta.verified = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), authorMeta.signature = c("", 
"me seguem no tik Tok gentee meu Instagram é @deyse3760", "", 
"", "Sou um cara legal que adora tomar umas cervejas e fazer um bom churrasco...", 
"", "Jornalista | Pregador do Evangelho\n\nEX GLOBAL\nInsta:@erick_castrooficial", 
"muito obrigado pelo 90k ", "muito obrigado pelo 90k ", 
"muito obrigado pelo 90k "), authorMeta.avatar = c("https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1662059894232070~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=3jVCVxW73fDbv5a8uBjE1fMuJJ4%3D", 
"https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1663890951712774~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=K0TDOlOzj9bS799Mj8oOwSbWO4w%3D", 
"https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/3537e047a2d150a5a92818b60384bef8~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=OW8A5M8UcE%2FmxzDSrBf8prN1CdM%3D", 
"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/1080x1080/tos-alisg-avt-0068/d2023f10221a1d54c397daba7ccc0d6b.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=InxZURrUyON59BteEQh7bRb%2BwUk%3D", 
"https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/6101bb4cfb128c83b13fca38fd8ca287~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=sLrJEDFV9A5tNGjcfpwxyj7dGYw%3D", 
"https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/64e95501c830600a62821559501e07db~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=WjHD2HdtncdadQ7RzCgrHHNjtD4%3D", 
"https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/e30c6d0e954ec431cbb9aafaaf04dd8a~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=ExL8tsDlKLdjCQEVIaSuRPGkHjI%3D", 
"https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=fyUaERy2FytRbrfrwvoONCfvzok%3D", 
"https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=fyUaERy2FytRbrfrwvoONCfvzok%3D", 
"https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=aGj0%2BhUt%2B3IUSfSDhxaokf%2BqACY%3D"
), authorMeta.following = c(36L, 91L, 86L, 2091L, 17L, 103L, 
19L, 0L, 0L, 0L), authorMeta.fans = c(23L, 54L, 61L, 1741L, 5L, 
9L, 14900L, 103800L, 103800L, 103800L), authorMeta.heart = c(87L, 
536L, 5L, 9168L, 2L, 67L, 149400L, 1800000L, 1800000L, 1800000L
), authorMeta.video = c(13L, 90L, 1L, 78L, 1L, 7L, 45L, 1388L, 
1388L, 1388L), authorMeta.digg = c(27L, 101L, 772L, 6976L, 429L, 
203L, 202L, 1964L, 1964L, 1964L), musicMeta.musicId = c(6808524996944628736, 
6814115937994755072, 6817770512362654720, 6945455736818371584, 
6949634983900351488, 6970340831324605440, 6971908113897098240, 
6973073959780731904, 6.973112023635e+18, 6973333140853115904), 
    musicMeta.musicName = c("som original", "som original", "som original", 
    "som original", "som original", "som original", "som original", 
    "som original", "som original", "som original"), musicMeta.musicAuthor = c("Aguiar Sillva Barbei", 
    "Tik Toker", "Lennon Rikelme", "Fernando Medeiros", "user9898887549048", 
    "diverticity", "Erick Rosário", "Ramon Santos", "Ramon Santos", 
    "Ramon Santos"), musicMeta.musicOriginal = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), musicMeta.musicAlbum = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), musicMeta.playUrl = c("https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/1662238588713990.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/1663603269018645.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/1664496548264966.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/6945455944255998726.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/6949635075508144902.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/6970340898207025925.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/6971908181308099334.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/6973074061354191622.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/6973112153297849093.mp3", 
    "https://sf16-ies-music-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/musically-maliva-obj/6973333227930929925.mp3"
    ), musicMeta.coverThumb = c("https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1662059894232070~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=a1nedaPq0w3fUNs5D22xou27Z%2Bc%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1594805258216454~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=i2VoIQdaLgOIlElF4mtFV9fj36E%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1663882871894021~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=w2LXI2Vx7B8hNRu%2FkMzKzJG81K8%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/100x100/tos-alisg-avt-0068/d2023f10221a1d54c397daba7ccc0d6b.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=wkmBrklJdcU39hh9FxjCIyoMMqI%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/6101bb4cfb128c83b13fca38fd8ca287~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=I4CPAUy9pAnJNEodE%2FrRXNvG5zY%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/64e95501c830600a62821559501e07db~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=PnoiAzDZ0qjn5gcXmgGpA12Fhww%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/e30c6d0e954ec431cbb9aafaaf04dd8a~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=ycXJmPSP%2BoyeTy9Pu%2FB6O8gCqHM%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=%2FDtsgOj9hhwtvWxTcFU9xfzalZw%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=%2FDtsgOj9hhwtvWxTcFU9xfzalZw%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=%2FDtsgOj9hhwtvWxTcFU9xfzalZw%3D"
    ), musicMeta.coverMedium = c("https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1662059894232070~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=On0S4nK%2Bj0cj%2Bgc7Zj12gNThUTw%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1594805258216454~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=vCTDjooZXVQIrMnqUEATBgA2IkY%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1663882871894021~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=rJiFs4s%2BruqpkZniOSH52THHdZI%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/720x720/tos-alisg-avt-0068/d2023f10221a1d54c397daba7ccc0d6b.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=dBlHfEjQmyY6bcTKbN1ZFM%2FweFs%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/6101bb4cfb128c83b13fca38fd8ca287~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=VXZNIjK%2F8Pb76ae6T1OEopppdQU%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/64e95501c830600a62821559501e07db~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=PmEV2A4ZH60bT4aqD3gKfw7TCW8%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/e30c6d0e954ec431cbb9aafaaf04dd8a~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=1kuaJwOm%2BqqiJx7AsQszNy2NMr8%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=OveZTX%2BR936jcxq1B%2BwRtYZ4J6E%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=OveZTX%2BR936jcxq1B%2BwRtYZ4J6E%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=OveZTX%2BR936jcxq1B%2BwRtYZ4J6E%3D"
    ), musicMeta.coverLarge = c("https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1662059894232070~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=3jVCVxW73fDbv5a8uBjE1fMuJJ4%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1594805258216454~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=DSd1ljPdAH68x0r%2Fmc%2Fu12ZJZRo%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva-obj/1663882871894021~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=xpRL3daRlDn9LNFeSFcvA0AZGws%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/1080x1080/tos-alisg-avt-0068/d2023f10221a1d54c397daba7ccc0d6b.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=InxZURrUyON59BteEQh7bRb%2BwUk%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/6101bb4cfb128c83b13fca38fd8ca287~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=sLrJEDFV9A5tNGjcfpwxyj7dGYw%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/64e95501c830600a62821559501e07db~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=WjHD2HdtncdadQ7RzCgrHHNjtD4%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/e30c6d0e954ec431cbb9aafaaf04dd8a~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=ExL8tsDlKLdjCQEVIaSuRPGkHjI%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=fyUaERy2FytRbrfrwvoONCfvzok%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=fyUaERy2FytRbrfrwvoONCfvzok%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/b4fab700030364d677fcfff56d7aa97d~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1645729200&x-signature=aGj0%2BhUt%2B3IUSfSDhxaokf%2BqACY%3D"
    ), musicMeta.duration = c(60L, 10L, 14L, 24L, 18L, 59L, 14L, 
    180L, 180L, 180L), covers.default = c("https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/cba99e4cfab94a30932daf9bd8a46aa9?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=HmbzlKuZcnhJJdJTDpujB9JElMs%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/e9bbf48d5fff4f399c1568090067e4c9?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=vi4vhiZA6dRelsrXz6oUYmEqRek%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/271443a40840420abf0ecd036e93b0c4?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=mqthAEBfkyi56%2Fu8MC0xJbi4omA%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/539c578051b043d8889a0e82b32a214c?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=zBv3io%2BZd%2Bj%2Bj8Dtqh8TDGf%2FT4E%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/306c760b089741f7bbb2dbaddc714c31?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=HcAc%2FRN0dV57JmGwQxbU%2BrDpp1E%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/e987bd46d1ad48258264bf8847588f3e?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=26NvQDYhNN48exwTgCchKFZ%2FH6Y%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/aab8becb2c4d4e5292446c470f33f186?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=shVdO9EvuLLxjqbNdep4WRoUeMs%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/e60326c0b2fb40a986bec1a1128123f7?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=eGdid0FIXehKUfSTny5S%2FEWgf%2B8%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/10bd7e951b39441292b3364c374ce0e8?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=C7ehfu%2FaHzAbPOOp4WBjZwxzsrY%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/9b5285ab683a4c928c2fd19a1f1fcad4?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=Ia%2BnIAVQYYhboyQ84afNrkOSfRE%3D"
    ), covers.origin = c("https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/88a5033dfd6f411a9f233455685fa975_1585235839?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=ChSD93ExjeuP0Bl4Mppiug%2F%2BVAI%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/483d9a6ae7fd4ae4a307c8f4b2cede68_1586563171?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=Kat8K7YUp4skHR4Dg143lkFUwBo%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/25836970e87040739a72ee538bdaba99_1589240164?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=%2FNA63Ve%2BEndyFYZJjiHLix3Xa7w%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/b14fa4a08ce74d618ad8a2a426282c84_1617114990?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=J27jTvMFfhY0ue%2FFETdOcj9zWtU%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/f8a1e34f99e549cf879e0d579dc0707d_1618091022?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=ub%2F3iB0ZeprBm6%2Fa%2B0IQbpXHLiQ%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/b9f7d74e798c4e6bbc6a0c562853497d_1622908973?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=wRsztCSJ9SnNU8H4VjnHgZ3gZbM%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/bac4272ae8b14ca38e5fedfc1dfc40ce_1623273879?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=yadqVt9uR3RPNBCE72YLMtG3ROE%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/558cec2e9a184db590a07a4405ed5702_1623545323?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=Q9hSOOQoKd8nO8K73yPYVudm4iQ%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/fb68eb9a289d4828a7371a2f7a178f2d_1623554205?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=l1k4xFcTaDSEIL2VOPwxUhQeNX0%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/b1a0e437d39b440ea0e405112949d220_1623605646?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=vz13KzRITsWUyseBduWTOz2xZ4E%3D"
    ), covers.dynamic = c("https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/1c3ce2c68cff4f0982410301f60f0246_1585235840?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=U%2FbcCJuu9u8T%2FmfARMAPO1fntPM%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/82136e8de6ef4febb646a98a292437a0_1586563170?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=%2FPKHw0L2fLSUjMe5DsqjEKcuoSo%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/d44ba90030974009bf0d7beb44ca8386_1589240164?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=CiGmFb54%2BLBSpY5eNHyz8%2Frvdv4%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/26f3c1c442b24d6cb7644ece3f54efd0_1617114990?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=JUMoVTx7I4aPnwJVd1zv%2FZ%2BREPE%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/16308aa2d9724d9196a1cce526394eb2_1618091023?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=RsVbM%2F5afCuWHtDLG%2BC1le9XadA%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/9e83a88c4cc348139ff6960234609216_1622908972?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=HS4axvDTaDG4hAydkhreGSOkrqg%3D", 
    "https://p77-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/acfd4f691fff44dc9bd9a01380404701_1623273879?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=39iKVMxfom1RA7ahLnnxEDj%2BBW4%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/4a0c1930f9ce4809ae44ef25405a4370_1623545322?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=SpLVaS5vDUGxTWj%2BfKlKJva%2F20A%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/0d653827737745a8a006b2cc7ffd9640_1623554208?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=C93vK7%2BNxFufYmDbNVJd7QdF0pI%3D", 
    "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/ccfa2a83ae1d48e091a637413f7eb7f7_1623605649?x-expires=1645664400&x-signature=zXwlq3sMW0xAVNdMryTY0rDUCUc%3D"
    ), videoUrl = c("https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/38ac26a15637fe281520b4fe9fb95434/6216dacb/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/f4e27ded4ea64efca5f18e1a5d8393dd/?a=1988&br=2570&bt=1285&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=2&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7TheyLUDXq&l=202202231908300101921662190507E861&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M3g2cTtqOWhmczMzODczM0ApNmY4NzY8aTxmNztnPDVmOmdpYy9vZV5eYXJfLS1fMTZzczBfNDExNjVfNi4uLWJeYWI6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/86c8384953c1838b24b4908a5e4f1291/6216da8f/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/47def1dbd3b24722ac7fa683975e355f/?a=1988&br=2470&bt=1235&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7Th2yLUDXq&l=2022022319082701019103203909060E21&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M2t4bWVveHdqdDMzaDczM0ApN2Y3ZmlmPGU7N2lkNzRmM2djbjBxY25uNjVfLS02MTZzcy4yYWExL15jYDVfX14yXmI6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/324b378f81c3556ebf50cbcd2c377b5e/6216da99/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c001/30287829751d482f815a0d7ca95c7bbd/?a=1988&br=1318&bt=659&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7Th2yLUDXq&l=2022022319082701019103203909060E21&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=ajU3czhpPDx4dDMzZzczM0ApNDU4NTc3Z2QzN2hlMzszNWdrL3EzL2ZnLnBfLS02MTZzc2AuLzBgMDYtNC0uLmAzMGE6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/1e9995549209307bfa123aea504b8fe8/6216daa5/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/2bb71ae377de438cba8316d317ca572e/?a=1988&br=1416&bt=708&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=2&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7Th0yLUDXq&l=202202231908290101921662190507E745&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=MzZzeTM8dW9tNDMzNzczM0ApOjZnZzY3ZWVmNzppOzM2OGdzNWpjbTU1YmVgLS1kMTZzcy9jLS40Ni8zMTIuM2AwX2A6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/5a37234b8ce3450d432ebc076799778d/6216da9e/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/c8ca04f8887f43739ff6164d01677c4a/?a=1988&br=1440&bt=720&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7ThzyLUDXq&l=202202231908280102231230141108A10D&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=anhmb3E7dXAzNDMzNzczM0ApaDhmNWRoOztlN2VoaTRpaWdvajVsM2wvbG1gLS1kMTZzcy9fYi82XzY1Xi1fX181LjM6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/c37cc04b74d23c7072ac20f090566a37/6216dac8/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/2043d6424b2d40bd8c8067ba6c560530/?a=1988&br=1384&bt=692&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7Th0yLUDXq&l=202202231908290101921662190507E745&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=MzZ1eHZpb3VzNTMzNzczM0ApNTc8OmVnO2VkN2lkNjpoaWdrMDQ0ZGQwcHFgLS1kMTZzcy4uYy4zYWNjYzQyYzMwYDU6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/6e1fded31f24294541cc6d269ec98dad/6216da96/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/9ada809b0c424b5ebb51385cda626c84/?a=1988&br=1528&bt=764&cd=0%7C0%7C1%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7ThGyLUDXq&l=202202231908230102230790121703D465&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M25wOjs1NXNtNjMzNzczM0ApaGQ5Njw2OjtnN2Y3Z2ZpZ2dhcS0ybzYvLy1gLS1kMTZzczIwY18tYy8xLmMuNDVjLi46Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/ccb06d3c99f07676e58957a16c0c45eb/6216db32/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/ca0670f6ce1f473583cd082de3472250/?a=1988&br=1060&bt=530&cd=0%7C0%7C1%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7ThVyLUDXq&l=202202231908140101901860440C08645A&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M2V4M21rdXNvNjMzNzczM0ApNThkZTM7OTw5NzZnNjY2OWczMGluaWkzNS9gLS1kMTZzcy1eMV81LzZiLS4tYi8xLV86Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/4cd95bfd3e5f6615a0a82397b4bc8047/6216db32/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/58edeec6ee0a4681b02e7372657fbc3c/?a=1988&br=1108&bt=554&cd=0%7C0%7C1%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7ThVyLUDXq&l=202202231908140101901860440C08645A&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M29wczRrazhxNjMzNzczM0ApZzc8PDk4ZjtpNzo4ZTo5aWcyL2ZqMTUyYy9gLS1kMTZzc2FiY142NDI1LS42LzM2YDA6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=", 
    "https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/478c09e780bccef0f118a1b011401f5e/6216db35/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/1df136f0b22e4a32b91deb41eda134aa/?a=1988&br=690&bt=345&cd=0%7C0%7C1%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=XOQ9-3._nz7ThOyLUDXq&l=2022022319081701022307215816072093&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M3g7Z2ZzMzQ3NjMzNzczM0ApNTg2ODwzaGQ3NzczO2c2NGdrZjFqcHM1LjBgLS1kMTZzc2JeNTQuXmEzMi82MS1iYjE6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr="
    ), videoUrlNoWaterMark = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), videoApiUrlNoWaterMark = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), videoMeta.height = c(480L, 1024L, 1024L, 
    480L, 576L, 1024L, 1024L, 1024L, 1024L, 1024L), videoMeta.width = c(848L, 
    576L, 576L, 848L, 1024L, 576L, 576L, 576L, 576L, 576L), videoMeta.duration = c(60L, 
    4L, 14L, 24L, 18L, 59L, 14L, 180L, 180L, 180L), diggCount = c(2L, 
    6L, 5L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 33L, 30200L, 23900L, 663L), shareCount = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1540L, 468L, 37L), playCount = c(30L, 
    57L, 74L, 385L, 23L, 24L, 2783L, 930500L, 430600L, 34600L
    ), commentCount = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 224L, 205L, 
    16L), downloaded = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), mentions = c("[]", "[]", "[]", 
    "[]", "[]", "[]", "[]", "[\"@luizguilhermeol2\"]", "[\"@vinicius\"]", 
    "[]"), hashtags = c("[{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"56170\",\"name\":\"mentira\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"1661865863689221\",\"name\":\"lulaxbolsonaro\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1648865153779717\",\"name\":\"bolsonaro2022\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"42164\",\"name\":\"foryou\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1518647\",\"name\":\"fory\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1105452\",\"name\":\"fyyy\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"48919866\",\"name\":\"golpista\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"37986936\",\"name\":\"obrigadogalera\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"71910226\",\"name\":\"flamengooooo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1653550338924549\",\"name\":\"paravocefo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1688242636665861\",\"name\":\"dublagem19\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1699304938756101\",\"name\":\"flamengosergipe\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"44804\",\"name\":\"copaamerica\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"4296838\",\"name\":\"flamengo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1650748975425541\",\"name\":\"flamengolibertadores\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"5064773\",\"name\":\"eriksen\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1650748975425541\",\"name\":\"flamengolibertadores\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"4296838\",\"name\":\"flamengo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"44804\",\"name\":\"copaamerica\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1699304938756101\",\"name\":\"flamengosergipe\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1688242636665861\",\"name\":\"dublagem19\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"83884\",\"name\":\"neymar\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"45874915\",\"name\":\"globol\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]", 
    "[{\"id\":\"83884\",\"name\":\"neymar\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"5064773\",\"name\":\"eriksen\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1662240138893317\",\"name\":\"globolixoo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1650748975425541\",\"name\":\"flamengolibertadores\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1688242636665861\",\"name\":\"dublagem19\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1699304938756101\",\"name\":\"flamengosergipe\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"44804\",\"name\":\"copaamerica\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"88764338\",\"name\":\"foryoupage\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"30873973\",\"name\":\"paravoce\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1663903392662534\",\"name\":\"globolixooo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"4296838\",\"name\":\"flamengo\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1105452\",\"name\":\"fyyy\",\"title\":\"\",\"cover\":\"\"}]"
    ), effectStickers = c("[]", "[{\"id\":\"333023\",\"name\":\"Humor de feriado\"}]", 
    "[]", "[]", "[]", "[]", "[]", "[]", "[]", "[]")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UpdateII** removed previous solutions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(hashtags, sep = '\",\"name\":\"') %>% 
  separate_rows(hashtags, sep = '\",\"title\"') %>% 
  filter(str_detect(hashtags, '^[\\w]')) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(hashtags = toString(hashtags), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
hashtags                                                                                        
   <chr>                                                                                           
 1 globolixoo                                                                                      
 2 globolixoo                                                                                      
 3 globolixoo                                                                                      
 4 globolixoo                                                                                      
 5 globolixoo                                                                                      
 6 globolixoo, mentira                                                                             
 7 lulaxbolsonaro, globolixoo, bolsonaro2022, foryou, fory, fyyy, golpista, obrigadogalera         
 8 flamengooooo, paravocefo, dublagem19, flamengosergipe, copaamerica, flamengo, flamengolibertado…
 9 globolixoo, flamengolibertadores, flamengo, copaamerica, flamengosergipe, dublagem19, neymar, g…
10 neymar, eriksen, globolixoo, flamengolibertadores, dublagem19, flamengosergipe, copaamerica, fo…
```

Comment: so, this way works in a way that i can only extract the first hashtag, so it wouldn't be very nice to the scraped posts that contain more than one — some on the reproducible example, for instance. i would need to extract every single instance of ("name":"hashtag") in the column.

Comment: oh, thank you! that already helps me a lot :) my only doubt is if it would be possible to group the hashtags that co occur in the same dataframe cells, separated by comma. for instance, something like "flamengooooo,paravocefo,dublagem19,..." and so on for row 8.